# Latex math symbol |=

Tags: symbols, math-operators

Is there a command for this symbol in Latex? |=. If I use | and = in the source code, then in the pdf there is a big gap between them.

The symbol is from math (from logical clauses). I'm not exactly sure how to translate it in english, it kinda means "resolves" and it used like this c |= C.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, are you trying to use something similar to `\models` relative operator\symbol (whatever :D)?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/82917.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is a relative operator defined by `\models`

I think you can use this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $c\models C$
\end{document}
```

to get as shown below

[image]

Moreover, as @campa pointed out try looking up for the symbol as well.

Also, another option is using `\vDash` (as ''campa'' pointed told us in comments) that is available in `amssymb` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    $c\vDash C$
\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Yea, it's the double turnstile symbol.

Comment: There is also `\vDash` from the `amssymb` package which looks quite similar. Technical note: pinging with '@name' doesn't work in questions and answers, only in comments `:-)`.

Comment: @campa Didnt knew it before :) Thanks for the note.

Comment: @SilentControl Honestly, I don't know what a 'double turnstile symbol' is. So, I hope this helps.

Comment: @Campa Updated the answer with `\vDash` as well.